# Vector reshaping on the V-element in HSV of an image

Tags: matlab

I have n vectors which i want to "stretch" into a start- and stopvalues.
Like this: [Example of linear mapping.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8LVE.png) In this example n=4 where "in" is the original values and "ut" is the desired values.
What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Example:
I have a vector of 35535 elements sorted in ascending order. The lowest value is 0.09 and the highest 0.36. I also have two start and stop values, 0 and 0.5, (n is 2, 2 segments).
What i want is to "stretch" the values in my vector to reach from 0.09-0.36 to 0.5 while keeping their relative distance to eachother.

Edit:
Another image to try and make it clearer
[n is 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoMow.png),
[n is 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnqzS.png),

Edit 2:
[Another image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGxG9.png)

Comment: Could you please give a numerical example to clarify your question?

Comment: @OmG I added an example. :D

Comment: Please provide a [complete and minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a minimal input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: Thanks guys for ur time and interest. I think i found the answer and it's really silly so i'm just gonna delete this post. Again, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time thinking of my problem I realized I was getting distracted by "Linear mapping" and that the solution to what i wanted to do was simply using
Y = kx+m. Where i calculate Y and keep my "x" value.

For example:
If my startvalue is 0/stopvalue is 0.5 and lowest value is 0.09/highest value is 0.36. Then k = (0.5-0)/(0.36-0.09), m = 0-k*0.09.
Then y = k * x + m. If we put in 0.09 in x we get very close to 0. If x is 0.36, y is 0.5.

I was working with images and for me it was important to remember to keep the y AND x values so that i could reassemble the image after the operation.